# Rendered image only shows a small frame

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

this is what I want to render:
[image]

but this is what I get:
[image]

Comment: please post screen shot of the camera settings and render settings.

Comment: Pick "HDTV 1080p" preset from small popup menu at top right of "Dimensions" section of "Output" tab.